# Open Drive app to create file and get link back

Tags: android, google-drive-api, scanning

I want to use google drive app on android to scan some documents, create file and then get the link. I know there's a google api which I can use but then I would have to implement my own document scanner.

Answer (score 0):

For the scanning of documents, try checking out Google Drive's own [OCR feature](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/176692?hl=en), though it might be pretty limited. As for the creation of files, you can use Google Drive API's [`DriveResourceClient.createFile()`](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/create-file#programmatically) method.

> When you call `DriveResourceClient.createFile()`, the Drive for Android API places the new file in the folder that you passed in as an argument.

After creating the file, you can get the file's `webViewLink` property for the link. `webViewLink` is a link for opening the file in a relevant Google editor or viewer in a browser.